# keras: extracting weights using get_weights function

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer, deeplearning4j

I would like to extract weights of 1d CNN layer, and understand how exactly the prediction values are computed. I am not able to re-produce the prediction values using the weights from `get_weights()` function.

In order to explain my understanding, here is a small data set.

```
n_filter = 64
kernel_size = 10
len_timeseries = 123
n_feature = 3
X = np.random.random(sample_size*len_timeseries*n_feature).reshape(sample_size,len_timeseries,n_feature)
y = np.random.random(sample_size*(len_timeseries-kernel_size+1)*n_filter).reshape(sample_size,
                                                                                  (len_timeseries-kernel_size+1),
                                                                                  n_filter)
```

Now, create a simple 1d CNN model as:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(n_filter,kernel_size,
                 input_shape=(len_timeseries,n_feature)))
model.compile(loss="mse",optimizer="adam")
```

Fit the model and predict the values of `X` as:

```
model.fit(X,y,nb_epoch=1)
y_pred = model.predict(X)
```

The dimension of `y_pred` is `(1000, 114, 64)` as it should.

Now, I want to reproduce the value of `y_pred[irow,0,ilayer]]` using weights stored in `model.layer`. As there is only single layer, `len(model.layer)=1`. So I extract the weights from the first and the only layer as:

```
weight = model.layers[0].get_weights()
print(len(weight))
> 2 
weight0 = np.array(weight[0])
print(weight0.shape)
> (10, 1, 3, 64)
weight1 = np.array(weight[1])
print(weight1.shape)
> (64,)
```

The weight has length 2 and I assume that the 0th position contain the weights for features and the 1st position contain the bias.
As the `weight0.shape=(kernel_size,1,n_feature,n_filter)`, I thought that I can obtain the values of `y_pred[irow,0,ilayer]` by:

```
ifilter = 0
irow = 0
y_pred_by_hand = weight1[ifilter] + np.sum( weight0[:,0,:,ifilter] * X[irow,:kernel_size,:])
y_pred_by_hand
> 0.5124888777
```

However, this value is quite different from `y_pred[irow,0,ifilter]` as:

```
 y_pred[irow,0,ifilter]
 >0.408206
```

Please let me know where I got wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You have misunderstood the `weights` attribute here. What you are looking for is the `output` attribute of the layer which is the result given by `model.predict`. This can be obtained by `layer.output`. Typically a `Layer` is fed with an input tensor and is acted upon by the `weights` matrix which depends on the type of layer being used. This computation gives an output tensor which is what you are looking for.

For example consider a simple Dense layer with input tensor A of shape (1,3), an output sigmoid layer  emitting a tensor B (1,1) and a weight matrix W. The shape of W is determined based on the input and output shapes. So in this case a Dense layer does `A matmul W` and the result of this is going to be the prediction B. W's shape will be determined as (3,1) only which can result in an output shape of (1,1). So what you are looking for is B, however you are trying to access W.

Comment: May I ask how you define "B" in your example?

Comment: You are right that I want to have "B" (result given by model.predict). But for that I can simply use model.predict. The reason why I want "B" is to understand how the weights are used together with the input tensor "X" to calculate "B". Seems like the way I calculated B using weights is wrong because it does not agree to the output of model.predict.